# NodeJS: bcrypt is returning false even when the password is correct

Tags: sql, node.js, passport.js, bcrypt

I am having trouble with the bcrypt.compare portion of my code. My route is able to hash the password and store the password in the database. The database is able to store 255 characters and I have verified that the password is 60 characters long. Every time I compare the password to the hashed password on the db, I get a false returned on from bycrypt.compare.

Has anyone encountered this and know what I may be doing wrong?

Auth Route for creating the user in the database:

```
    app.post('/register/local', async (req, res) => {
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10) || undefined
    const existingLocalUser = await db.User.findOne({ where: { email: req.body.email } }) || undefined
      if (!existingLocalUser) {
          try {
            const newUser = await db.User.create({
                given_name: req.body.given_name,
                family_name: req.body.family_name,
                email: req.body.email,
                password: hashedPassword,
              }
              )
              res.redirect('/login')
          } catch {
              res.redirect('/register')
          }
      } else if (existingLocalUser.dataValues.google_id) {
        const updateUser = await db.User.update(
            { password: hashedPassword },
            { where: { email: req.body.email } }
          )
        } else {
            console.log("You already have an account. Please login.")
            res.redirect('/login');
        }
})
```

Local Strategy from Passport:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy( async (username, password, done) => {
  const existingLocalUser = await User.findOne({ where: { email: username }})
      if (!existingLocalUser) {
        console.log("No user exisits")
        return done(null, false)
      }
          console.log("password", password)
          console.log("existingLocalUser.password", existingLocalUser.password)
          await bcrypt.compare(password, existingLocalUser.dataValues.password, function(error, result) {
            if (error) {
              return done(error)
            } else if (result) {
              return done(null, existingLocalUser)
            } else {
              return done(null, false)
            }
          })
  }
));
```

Answer (score 0):

> 

```js
 bcrypt.compare(password, existingLocalUser.password, function(error, result) {
            if (error) {
              return done(error)
            } else if (result) {
              return done(null, existingLocalUser)
            } else {
              return done(null, false)
            }
          })
```

You are trying to use callback and await together, kindly remove await and stick to callbacks or you refactor and use async-await alone

Comment: Thanks for the insight on that. I removed the await but I am still getting a false returned.. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As @cristos rightly pointed out the problem could be that you are mixing up async/await and callbacks. Stick to one pattern.
Here's how your code would be with async/await,

```
try {
  const result = await bcrypt.compare(password, existingLocalUser.password);

  if (result) {
    return done(null, existingLocalUser);
  } else {
    return done(null, false);
  }
} catch (error) {
  return done(error);
}
```

Also on another note, are you sure you are comparing the correct values?
Going by the code sample you have provided I can see that you are logging,

```
console.log("password", password)
console.log("existingLocalUser.password", existingLocalUser.password)
```

However, the values compared in `bcrypt.compare()` is different,

```
bcrypt.compare(password, existingLocalUser.dataValues.password)
```

Comment: I tried this as well and unfortunately, the result is that it still returns false.

Comment: @KevinT I have updated the answer with more details

Comment: Ah, yes sorry about that. existingLocalUser.dataValues.password and existingLocalUser.password returns the same values. I was testing both ways which is why you see it like this.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why it wasn't working... React or Redux was masking the password with asterisks so changing it to a sting of asterisks which gets hashed..